# JSDoc: how to specify optional return value properly

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

My task is to document function with right JSDoc. When function returns **true** it triggers something, otherwise it doesn't. But in any case the return value must be of boolean type.

My variant is:

```
* @return {boolean=false} trigger for default event handler:
*
* Value | Description
*-------|-------------------------------
* true  | disable default event handler
* false | enable default event handler
```

Help me please to choose right solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added simply one line below possible return values:

```
* @return {boolean} trigger for default event handler:
*
* Value | Description
*-------|-------------------------------
* true  | disable default event handler
* false | enable default event handler
*
* Return `false` or nothing if you want that default event handler stayed untouched.
```

I think this is the best solution because it is clear and valid.